# Typescript type definition for FunctionComponent and children

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

I'm trying to get my head around typescript, I'm fairly new to it and losing it a bit behind the syntax.
I'm trying to define a HOC to wrap things around in my tests.

```
import React, {FunctionComponent, ReactNode} from 'react';
import {ThemeProvider} from "styled-components";
import theme from "../components/Global/theme/theme.style";

const mountWithTheme: FunctionComponent = ({children}: { children?: ReactNode }) => (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>{children}</ThemeProvider>
);

export default mountWithTheme;
```

Now, I know there's a type in React

```
type PropsWithChildren<P> = P & { children?: ReactNode };
```

How can I use it in my definition to avoid reinventing the wheel? The type definition is not really clear to me, I tried

```
{children}: PropsWithChildren
```

and

```
const mountWithTheme: FunctionComponent<PropsWithChildren> = ({children}) => {...}
```

but none of the two seem to work.

Comment: What are you trying to acheive by using `PropsWithChildren<P>`?  Do you want to make a generic component and pass through the props?

Answer (score 0):

You can define your component giving it the props type as an argument :

```
import React, {FunctionComponent} from 'react';

type MyProps = {
  color: "red"
}

const mountWithTheme: FunctionComponent<MyProps> = (props) => (
  <div color={props.color}>{props.children}</div>
);
```

`props` will be of type `PropsWithChildren<MyProps>` but FunctionComponent is doing it for you.